# What can you do to secure a shed door?

Tags: security, shed

Any advice on the best ways to secure a shed door from intruders?  I'm considering interlocking hinges, and a bolt-cutter "proof" hasp lock.  Anything else I should consider?

Comment: You best security is to not put small valuable items in there.  A table saw, or lawnmower is probably ok.  A chain saw or skill saw or cordless drill, likely to be stolen.

Answer (score 3):

Easy: Motion detection lights.

[image]

Difficult: Alarm system.

[image]

High maintenance: Guard dog.

[image]

Anything can be broken into by a determined thief, the idea is to make your place less attractive of a target than the next place.

[image]

Comment: If there is no power at the shed they make solar powered units.

Comment: You forgot locks, electric fence, security guards, and razor wire.